# Why doesn't App Module exist in Angular 17?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have downloaded with npm the new version of Angular and I haven't seen the *app.module.ts* file.

Has it been eliminated from the project structure?

[Visual Studio Code files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CpjW.png).

I have tried creating a new one. It seems odd.

Comment: I have use npm install -g angular-cli. I have obtained the last version, thus I download the files through it. I'm in a course where app.module.ts is needed but I haven't have the file.

Comment: Ok. But why it doesn't exist? Have been taken off in the new version?

Comment: The default for --standalone is still false in the `ng new` command. See https://angular.dev/cli/new. So nothing stopping you ng new-ing a module based project. The reason why angular is moving towards standalone is because standalone applications are generally simpler to reason about. A component directly imports what it needs. But NgModule are still fully supported with interoperability with standalone components.

Comment: Actually, docs looks wrong, `ng new --standalone=false` to keep NgModule. Similar for `ng generate  --standalone=false` commands

Comment: create a new project angular 17 with app module "ng new test --no-standalone

Answer (score 102, accepted):

From Angular v17 onwards, Standalone is now the new default for the CLI.

So when you create a new project, you won't have any modules in it if you don't specify anything.

However, it is still possible to create a module-based app by using the `--no-standalone` flag : `ng new --no-standalone`

Standalone components are a feature introduced in v14. With the change in v17, the Angular team [strongly recommends to use them](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-angular-v17-4d7033312e4b#586d) as they are easier to use, understand and are require less boilerplate.

For tutorials using standalone components, I advise you to get a look at [the new documentation site](https://angular.dev).

Comment: so how can we add lazy loaded route to a standalone app ?

Comment: use `provideRouter()` in `app.config.ts` !

Comment: The part that tries to answer the OP's question "Why App Module doesn't exist in Angular 17?" is really short for my taste. This answer just recommends to disable the default setting. Why not elaborating more the reasons, WHY the Angular team made the decision to make apps standalone by default? Now this may result in beginners doing old/deprecated things when learning with Angular.

Comment: @MartinSchneider I can guarantee that beginners are doing old/deprecated things. I've just started learning Angular and I'm struggling with an issue, and every bit of guidance I can find tells me to put something in the file that doesn't exist. Frameworks are supposed to make things simpler or quicker or both, but the Angular team doesn't seem to have gotten the memo.

Comment: I've added some additional informations. Believe me, you really want to use standalone components.

Comment: @MartinSchneider I agree. I'm not an angular expert, but it's my go-to front-end. I'm mainly a back-end developer. But I find that many times when the Angular version changes, they put in these breaking changes that really screw you up. This particular one has been a pain in my back side all morning.
I've been using C# .NET since version 1.0 and MS has NEVER done anything like this. They introduced .NET Core, but the .NET Framework remains and is still backwards compatible back to 1.0 in most respects.
For people that don't follow Angular regularly, this is a big pain point.

Comment: I feel like the explanation in the link is very incomplete compared to https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

Comment: create a new project angular 17 with app module "ng new test --no-standalone

Comment: Please note migration tutorial from angular doc if you need to see before/after result  : https://angular.io/guide/standalone-migration or angular v2 doc https://angular.dev/reference/migrations/standalone

Answer (score 2):

create a new project by running this cmd :
ng new projectName --no-standalone

this whould create the app.module.ts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).