# 'ng new app' not creating fil app.module.ts

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a angular new app using 'ng new appname'. After creating the app, I was able to run the application. When I include a new service with constructor argument httpclient, I am facing an error as like "No Provider for _httpclient".
My error screen in console :
[image: My error screen]

My code in service :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserinfoService {

  constructor(private htpsrvc : HttpClient) { }

  public GetEmployees() : any
  {
    //return this.htpsrvc.get("https://localhost:44387/api/Home")
  }
}
```

I had searched about the issue, and I found like there is no app.module.ts file in my folder structure.

I am not sure how did I miss the file app.module.ts, while creating the new application.

My angular version is 17 and node version is v18.18.2

Comment: Why -1 for my question ?

Comment: Use the new docs https://angular.dev/guide/di if you want to learn about standalone component model and how dependancy injection works under this model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `providedHttpClient()` to the providers in your `app.config.ts`

Comment: It works. What was the thing here I needs to learn ? And why I am not able to see app.module.ts file in folder structure. Please answer this, I want to accept your answer.

Comment: In v17 apps created by the CLI are standalone. They do not use module anymore.

Comment: If you want to create a module, see my other answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454741/why-app-module-doesnt-exist-in-angular-17/77457122#77457122

Comment: It(without module) is from v17 or from any previous versions ?

Comment: The default changed in v17 yes. We went from module by default, to standalone by default