# ng new does not generate app.module.ts in the src root folder Angular CLI 17.0.10

Tags: angular

I am creating new angular project using angular cli, I don't see the app.module.ts but instead I see Angular created a new file app.config.ts my Angular cli version is: Angular CLI 17.0.10

Is this a new way of registering the modules? but when I refer the docs still it mentions app.module.ts (https://angular.io/guide/file-structure) I was away couple of months from coding with Angular, any detailed guide would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, go through this [angular standalone components documentation](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77457122/13898633

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular 17 there are no modules anymore. If you want to keep the old structure (no longer recommended, other than for compatibility) use `--standalone` switch:

`ng new myapp --standalone false`

[docs](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components)

Comment: Also shoutout to the new docs https://angular.dev/